# Fog VSphere provider vm_clone request cannot use datastore in folder

Tags: ruby, fog, vsphere

The following code works great but only when the datastore specified is in the root of the datacenter. We organise our datastores in folders with the same name as the cluster they are associated with.
Tried putting a path in (e.g. dc_name/ds_name) but no good.

```
server=connection.vm_clone( 'datacenter'    => 'EWL', 
            'template_path' => '.Templates/RHEL 6.2 x64',
            'name'      => 'new_vm_name',
            'datastore'     => 'E2-CL01-T2-OS-015',
            'dest_folder'   => 'Self-Service',
            'transform' => 'sparse',
            'power_on'  => false )
```

Any clues?